# How to move a player around the square boundary?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying make a game wherein for each level, the character starts off by moving in a counter-clockwise direction around the inside border of the square over and over again (Shown in picture).
Also, the character should not be controlled by the user, it moves by itself around.

[The picture of my screen and how I want the square to function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3Oer.png)

I've tried using triggers, changing the position coordinates of the transform, and collision detections between the outer walls to change the direction of the character, but nothing seems to work. Here is some of the code I've tried for using the transform.MoveTowards method and the OnCollisionEnter2D function:

`public Vector2 targetPosition;`

`public Vector2 targetPosition2;`

`public Vector2 targetPosition3;`

`public Vector2 targetPosition4;`

`public float speed = 5f;`

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Bottom Wall")
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit");
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed *        Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (collision.collider.tag == "Right wall")
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition2, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

I have a feeling that the main problem is the fact that I cannot use the collision detection function in the fixed update function to make sure the character continuously moves towards the target.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated!